# Angular service for fetching and passing data with observables

Tags: javascript, typescript, observer-pattern, angular-2+

I have an Angular service consisting of three methods:

1. This method makes a call to my server to get a URL

   ```
   private itemUrl = "http://fooserver/api/get/item/details";
   getItemDetailsUrl(productId): Observable<any> {
       return this.http
           .get(this.itemUrl, {
               params: { productId: productId }
            })
           .flatMap(res => this.getItemDetails(res.json().itemUrl))
           .map(item => item);
   }
   ```
2. This takes that URL from #1 and grabs the XML data returned from the request and passes it to #3

   ```
   getItemDetails(url): Observable<any> {
       return this.http
           .get(url)
           .flatMap(item => this.parseItemFromUrl(item));
   }
   ```
3. The XML passed is then converted to a JSON object using a third party library and then returned:

   ```
   parseItemFromUrl(xml): any {
       let item;
       xml2js.parseString(xml.text(), function (err, result) {
           item = result.ItemLookupResponse.Items[0].Item[0];
       });
       return Observable.of(item);
   }
   ```

This code does return the expected JSON object back. But since this is my first time really using Observables, I'd like to know of any improvements or changes I could make and if I used the appropriate array methods in the appropriate places.

Comment: Just curious, can't the api you're calling just return json instead of xml?

Comment: I wish. The API is actually an Amazon API and unfortunately, they only return XML @C.M.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the improvements would be to use an `HttpClient` instead of `Http` for making the API calls.

If you use `HttpClient`, you won't have to call the `res.json()` everytime you `subscribe` to the response.

To use `HttpClient`, you'll first have to `import HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http`. Then you'll have to add it to the `imports` array of your `@NgModule` decorator.

Then you can inject `HttpClient` as a dependency and you will have access to the usual Http methods on the instance of `HttpClient` as well.

With that, you first part of the code will be reduced to:

```
private itemUrl = "http://fooserver/api/get/item/details";
getItemDetailsUrl(productId): Observable < any > {
  return this.http
    .get(this.itemUrl, {
      params: {
        productId: productId
      }
    })
    .flatMap(res => this.getItemDetails(res.itemUrl));
}
```

Also, I figured, there was a redundant `map` operation after the flatMap which wasn't really required. Rest all, I guess is in place in your code and I'm not really if it can be improved further. But I'll be looking out for answers to this question just in case.